# How to specify log link in glmnet?

Tags: r, glmnet

I'm running an elastic net on a generalized linear model with the glmnet and caret packages in R.

My response variable is cost (where cost > $0) and hence I'd like to specify a Gaussian family with a log link for my GLM. However glmnet doesn't seem to allow me to specify  `(link="log")` as follows:

```
> lasso_fit <- glmnet(x, y, alpha=1, family="gaussian"(link="log"), lambda.min.ratio=.001)
```

I've tried different variants, with and without quotations, but no luck. The glmnet documentation doesn't discuss how to include a log link.

Am I missing something? Does `family="gaussian"` already implicitly assume a log link?

Comment: I think this could be difficult.  If you dig into the `glmnet` code you'll see that `glmnet(..., family="gaussian")` calls `elnet` , which calls the Fortran `spelnet` function.  (Poisson regression calls `fishnet`, which calls `fishnet` or `spfishnet` (for dense vs sparse model matrices.) So I suspect someone would have to start from scratch to write a variant of elastic net that handled the log linkage ...

Answer (score 5):

It is a bit confusing, but the `family` argument in `glmnet` and `glm` are quite different. In `glm`, you can specify a `character` like `"gaussian"`, or you can specify a function with some arguments, like `gaussian(link="log")`. In `glmnet`, you can only specify the family with a `character`, like `"gaussian"`, and there is no way to automatically set the link through that argument.

The default link for `gaussian` is the `identity` function, that is, no transformation at all. But, remember that a link function is just a transformation of your `y` variable; you can just specify it yourself:

```
glmnet(x, log(y), family="gaussian")
```

Also note that the default link for the `poisson` family is `log`, but the objective function will change. See the Details under `?glmnet` in the first couple of paragraphs.

---

Your comments have led me to rethink my answer; I have evidence that it is **not correct**.

As you point out, there is a difference between E[log(Y)] and log(E[Y]). I think what the above code does is to fit E[log(Y)], which is not what you want. Here is some code to generate data and confirm what you noted in the comments:

```
# Generate data
set.seed(1)
x <- replicate(3,runif(1000))
y <- exp(2*x[,1] + 3*x[,2] + x[,3] + runif(1000))
df <- data.frame(y,x)

# Run the model you *want*
glm(y~., family=gaussian(link="log"), data=df)$coef
# (Intercept)          X1          X2          X3 
#   0.4977746   2.0449443   3.0812333   0.9451073 

# Run the model you *don't want* (in two ways)    
glm(log(y)~., family=gaussian(link='identity'), data=df)$coef
# (Intercept)          X1          X2          X3 
#   0.4726745   2.0395798   3.0167274   0.9957110 
lm(log(y)~.,data=df)$coef
# (Intercept)          X1          X2          X3 
#   0.4726745   2.0395798   3.0167274   0.9957110 

# Run the glmnet code that I suggested - getting what you *don't want*.
library(glmnet)
glmnet.model <- glmnet(x,log(y),family="gaussian", thresh=1e-8, lambda=0)
c(glmnet.model$a0, glmnet.model$beta[,1])
#        s0        V1        V2        V3 
# 0.4726745 2.0395798 3.0167274 0.9957110
```

Comment: Great, thank you. If I specify glmnet(x, log(y), family="gaussian") as you suggested, glmnet will actually be estimating log[E(y)] (which I want) rather than E[log(y)] (a loglinear OLS, which I don't want), is that correct?

Comment: To be honest, I didn't realize that log[E(y)] wasn't exactly equivalent to E[log(y)] until I looked it up five minutes ago. I ran some code to test that `glm(y~x,family=gaussian(link="log"))` was equivalent to `glm(log(y)~x,family=gaussian)`, and it was, so maybe I am missing something fundamental here.

Comment: Hmm, I double-checked on my own data, and I'm seeing different regression coefficients for glm(log(y)~x,family=gaussian) vs. glm(y~x,family=gaussian(link="log")), while lm(log(y)~x) and glm(log(y)~x,family=gaussian) produce identical coefficients.

Comment: You might have given me that check a little too soon. I reran some code, and realized that my answer is likely incorrect. I'll leave it up until a better answer comes along.

Comment: No worries - I'll check with the glmnet authors. I can't believe they overlooked this since GLMs on a Gaussian family with a log link is fairly common with healthcare cost data.

Comment: I can certainly believe they overlooked this.  It's not a trivial change, but probably one that requires a bit of rethinking of the underlying code/algorithm -- hopefully not too hard, but not something that they just forgot to include.

Comment: @BenBolker - I emailed Trevor Hastie, maybe I'm missing something. Otherwise it does sound like an interesting and challenging programming problem. :)

Comment: @RobertF Did you ever hear back?

Comment: @RNs_Ghost No - reading through nograpes's response again, the only other possibility is that using the Poisson link in glmnet is often used as an "equivalent" to a Gaussian family with a log link. However if you run the following code on nograpes toy dataset: `glmnet.model <- glmnet(x,y,family="poisson", thresh=1e-8, lambda=0); c(glmnet.model$a0, glmnet.model$beta[,1])`, the results still don't quite match the `glm()` model.

Answer (score 2):

I know that this is an old question, but in the current version of [glmnet](/questions/tagged/glmnet) (4.0-2) it **is** possible to use glm family functions as arguments to "family" instead of a character string, so you could use:

```
glmnet(x, y, family=gaussian(link="log"))
```

Note that the package is faster when you use the string arguments.

Reference:
https://glmnet.stanford.edu/articles/glmnetFamily.html